# How to add count up timer to datagridview cell C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, timer

I need to add count up timer to `DataGridView` in c#. When I run, it only count up value in cell at last row in `datagridview`. All the other cells in timer column displays zero

```
private void fillTodayPatientsTable()
{
    string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\sqlexpress;Database=dental;User Id=sa;Password=abc123;";
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string id = "";
        string firstname = "";
        string lastname = "";
        string startTime = "";
        DateTime attendedTime = DateTime.Now;
        string oString = "Select id,firstname,lastname,start_time,attended_time from Appointments";
        SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (oReader.HasRows)
            {
                DataTable dttable = new DataTable();
                DataColumn column;


                column = new DataColumn();
               // column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
                column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
                column.ColumnName = "Firstname";
                dttable.Columns.Add(column);

                column = new DataColumn();
                column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                column.ColumnName = "Lastname";
                dttable.Columns.Add(column);

                column = new DataColumn();
                column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                column.ColumnName = "Start time";
                dttable.Columns.Add(column);

                column = new DataColumn();
                column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                column.ColumnName = "Attended time";
                dttable.Columns.Add(column);

                lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                lbl.Font = new Font("TimesRoman", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
                dgStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgLabel);
                dgLabel.HeaderText = "Label Column";
                dgLabel.MappingName = "Name";
                dgLabel.Width = 200;
                dgStyle.PreferredRowHeight = 24;

                dttable.Columns.Add("Timer");

                labelll = new Label();
                col = col = new DataGridViewLabelCellColumn();

                int counter = 0;


                while (oReader.Read())
                {
                    id = oReader["id"].ToString();
                    firstname = oReader["firstname"].ToString();
                    lastname = oReader["lastname"].ToString();
                    startTime = oReader["start_time"].ToString();
                    attendedTime = (DateTime) oReader["attended_time"];
                    double attendedTimeStamp= (attendedTime - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime()).TotalSeconds;
                    double DateNowTimeStamp = (DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime()).TotalSeconds;
                    int waitingTime =(int) (DateNowTimeStamp - attendedTimeStamp);



                    row = dttable.NewRow();
                    row["Firstname"] = firstname;
                    row["Lastname"] = lastname;
                    row["Start time"] = startTime;
                    row["Attended time"] = attendedTime;
                    row["Timer"] = (waitingTime+counter).ToString();
                    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
                    dttable.Rows.Add(row);
                    countTest++;

                    timer1 = new Timer();
                    timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
                    timer1.Start();                         


                    dgvTodayPatient.DataSource = dttable;

                }
            }
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    if (counter ==60*60*24)
    timer1.Stop();
    row["Timer"] = counter.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for this
I put the timer inside form_load method and refresh the datagridview by adding `datafilling` method of datagridview into `timer1_Tick` event method

```
private void fillTodayPatientsTable()
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\sqlexpress;Database=dental;User Id=sa;Password=abc123;";
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string id = "";
                string firstname = "";
                string lastname = "";
                string startTime = "";
                DateTime attendedTime = DateTime.Now;
                string oString = "Select id,firstname,lastname,start_time,attended_time from Appointments";
                SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
                myConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (oReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        DataTable dttable = new DataTable();
                        DataColumn column;


                        column = new DataColumn();
                       // column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
                        column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
                        column.ColumnName = "Firstname";
                        dttable.Columns.Add(column);

                        column = new DataColumn();
                        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                        column.ColumnName = "Lastname";
                        dttable.Columns.Add(column);

                        column = new DataColumn();
                        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                        column.ColumnName = "Start time";
                        column.MaxLength = 200;
                        dttable.Columns.Add(column);

                        column = new DataColumn();
                        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
                        column.ColumnName = "Attended time";
                        dttable.Columns.Add(column);

                        lbl.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                        lbl.Font = new Font("TimesRoman", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
                        dgStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgLabel);
                        dgLabel.HeaderText = "Label Column";
                        dgLabel.MappingName = "Name";
                        dgLabel.Width = 200;
                        dgStyle.PreferredRowHeight = 24;

                        dttable.Columns.Add("Timer");

                        col = col = new DataGridViewLabelCellColumn();

                        //int counter = 0;


                        while (oReader.Read())
                        {
                            id = oReader["id"].ToString();
                            firstname = oReader["firstname"].ToString();
                            lastname = oReader["lastname"].ToString();
                            startTime = oReader["start_time"].ToString();
                            attendedTime = (DateTime) oReader["attended_time"];
                            double attendedTimeStamp= (attendedTime - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime()).TotalSeconds;
                            double DateNowTimeStamp = (DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime()).TotalSeconds;
                            int waitingTime =(int) (DateNowTimeStamp - attendedTimeStamp);

                            row = dttable.NewRow();
                            row["Firstname"] = firstname;
                            row["Lastname"] = lastname;
                            row["Start time"] = startTime;
                            row["Attended time"] = attendedTime;
                            //row["Timer"] = (counter).ToString();

                            TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitingTime);

                            string waitingTimeFormatted = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s",
                                            t.Hours,
                                            t.Minutes,
                                            t.Seconds,
                                            t.Milliseconds);
                            row["Timer"] = waitingTimeFormatted;

                            dttable.Rows.Add(row);
                            countTest++;

                            dgvTodayPatient.DataSource = dttable;

                        }
                    }
                    myConnection.Close();

                }                           

            }

        }        
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter == 60 * 60 * 24)
                timer1.Stop();
           // row["Timer"] = counter.ToString();
            fillTodayPatientsTable();
        }


        private void TodayPatient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            fillTodayPatientsTable();
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Start();


        }
```